# Why is my call to Zend Translate not working in the view?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-translate

In my view the call `$this->translate('test')` is not working.

In the bootstrap I have the following code to initiate the translations:

```
protected function _initTranslate() {
    $apc = $this->getOption('enable_apc_cache');
    if ($apc) {
        $cache = Zend_Registry::get('cache');
        Zend_Translate::setCache($cache);
    }

    // Set the correct locale
    $locale = new Zend_Locale('nl');
    Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Locale', $locale);


    // Form error translations
    $translator = new Zend_Translate(
        'array',
        APPLICATION_PATH.'/../resources/languages',
        'auto',
        array('scan' => Zend_Translate::LOCALE_DIRECTORY)
    );
    Zend_Form::setDefaultTranslator($translator);

    // All other translations, including form labels
    $translate = new Zend_Translate(
        'gettext',
        APPLICATION_PATH.'/../resources/languages/',
        'auto',
        array('scan' => Zend_Translate::LOCALE_DIRECTORY));
    Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Translate', $translate);
}
```

If I understand correctly (have searched on stackoverflow and Google) putting the translator in the registry with key `Zend_Translate` should to the trick.

Now in my view when I call `<?php echo $this->translate->_('Purchaseorder'); ?>` or `<?php echo $this->translate->('Purchaseorder'); ?>` it gives me an error.

`Call to a member function _() on a non-object` with the underscore call and `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'` without the underscore call.

What am I doing wrong/missing? According to http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.translate this should do the trick.

Comment: Seems you missing `;` at end of your statement !!

Comment: @RikeshShah It's not necessary (maybe it's neater) to have a semicolon at that place. Adding it doesn't solve it anyway. Added them to avoid confusion :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax should be:

```
<?php echo $this->translate('Purchaseorder'); ?>
```

You do use this syntax at the top of your post but it seems from the code you mention later on that you're actually using a different syntax there.

Comment: Overlooked that, thank you! I read the syntax quite a few times :/